# Managers - how would you feel about very negative feedback from a direct report?

Tags: management

I've recently started reporting to a manager who is very disruptive and is holding the team back. My peers (her other reports) are very friendly with her and they often hang out after work so I don't imagine they offer much criticism.

She loves to talk and regularly drags meetings 2 hours over their scheduled time to talk rubbish among other things.

I have a meeting scheduled to discuss my performance but I'd like to offer her some feedback on her own performance too. I think a lot of her criticism of me (such as being slow) is a knock-on affect of her being disruptive and wasting a lot of my time.

She is very confident and I'm worried that my feedback to her will not be taken well. Should I still offer my feedback or just let her get on with it?

Comment: If the meeting is about _your_ performance, do not try and make it about someone else's performance - your manager's or anyone else's.

Comment: Tread very lightly. The only way I see this ending well is if you phase is as how she can help you achieve her goals.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thanks for the response. Would you suggest discussing this in a 1-1 or not at all?

Comment: @IanJacobs Thanks for the response. I think she is very ambitious, so I'm trying to explain how she can build a higher performing team that will ultimately reflect well on her. She often asks why things are slow, but nobody is telling her its because she keeps distracting everybody.

Comment: The title appears to be asking for opinions.

Comment: I have learnt that manager can waste company's time (counted as productivity), but the direct-report can't!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a meeting scheduled to discuss my performance but I'd like to
> offer her some feedback on her own performance too.
>
> She is very confident and I'm worried that my feedback to her will not
> be taken well. Should I still offer my feedback or just let her get on
> with it?

If the intent of the meeting is to discuss *your* performance, it makes no sense to try and inject your opinion regarding *her* performance.

You already know it won't be received well. Just keep it to yourself, unless she specifically asks for your feedback regarding her performance.

Comment: Ok thanks. I should have phrased my question differently. The meeting is to discuss annual feedback from my coworkers. I did fill in annual feedback for her, but only included positive things because it was going to her boss. I want to discuss the negative issues in private with her and leave her boss out of it. I thought I was being considerate but now I just want to move to another team and forget about it!

Comment: That's correct. I will keep the feedback to myself then. I thought providing negative feedback privately would be more welcome than providing it to her boss directly as her boss asked me for feedback on her. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a meeting scheduled to discuss my performance but I'd like to
> offer her some feedback on her own performance too. I think a lot of
> her criticism of me (such as being slow) is a knock-on affect of her
> being disruptive and wasting a lot of my time.

Does she think everyone on her team is slow? Or just you?

I'm not saying you're totally incorrect with your assessment of her, but I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't some small tiny kernel of truth into what she's thinking about you.

In my opinion, you should focus on your own behavior, not hers. I bet it's going to be infinitely easier to change your own behavior than trying to change hers.

Ask yourself. Is there a kernel of truth about me being slow? What can I do to increase my speed? Or my perceived speed?

And don't say anything about her during your performance review, rightly or wrongly, it will come off as defensive. Your performance review is about your performance, not hers.